# How to stop eviction policy in memcached?

Tags: memcached

I come across the situation where I don't want any eviction policy(`LRU`)  in my `memcached server` setup . How to stop eviction policy in memcached ?

In other word is there any `noevicationpolicy` in memcached like redis have?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no such flag in memcached. Even if the items in your memcached storage have no expiration set, and it reaches a memory full state, it will start evicting least accessed slab from memory.